# update mysql left outer join ignores data and writes only one specific value

Tags: mysql, left-join

My attempt to update a big table using info from a small table, via LEFT OUTER JOIN, is filling all targeted cells with the same value-- regardless of the value in the small table.

How do I get the specific values from the small table written properly into the big table?

Here's the SQL:

```
UPDATE tablebig
LEFT OUTER JOIN tablesmall
ON tablebig.id AND tablesmall.id
SET tablebig.parameter1 = Sheet1.parameter1;
```

Here are the tables:

```
tablebig
========

id|email         |name   |parameter1|
-------------------------------------
1 |joe@joe.com   |joe    |
2 |jane@jane.com |jane   |
3 |sam@sam.com   |sam    |


tablesmall
==========

id|email         |parameter1|
-------------------------------------
1 |joe@joe.com   |good    |
2 |jane@jane.com |good    |
3 |sam@sam.com   |bad     |
```

OUTPUT:
All rows in tablebig currently having **good** written into parameter1, though the tablesmall parameter1 values, from which the tablebig.parameter1 values are taken, *do not* all have  **good** in parameter1.

How can I get the specific tablesmall.parameter1 values written accurately into tablebig.parameter1?

Thanks!

Comment: Sheet1.parameter1 - what's this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `ON` condition:

```
ON tablebig.id AND tablesmall.id
```

this will be true whenever tablebig.id and tablesmall.id are both non-zero, which is all the time. What you should have is:

```
ON tablebig.id = tablesmall.id
```

Also in your SET (I assume this is a typo) it should be

```
SET tablebig.parameter1 = tablesmall.parameter1;
```

So your query should be:

```
UPDATE tablebig
JOIN tablesmall
ON tablebig.id = tablesmall.id
SET tablebig.parameter1 = tablesmall.parameter1;
SELECT * FROM tablebig
```

which will give this result:

```
id  email           name    parameter1
1   joe@joe.com     joe     good
2   jane@jane.com   jane    good
3   sam@sam.com     sam     bad
```